# Rails 3: Request Timeout in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have upload a simple app to Heroku which works fine, however, after some time it stops working and all the GET requests just block.

I get this error:

```
2011-05-13T13:04:11+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/api/v1/69399ead0ed4ded38e7a101f7c8faf/2011-2-1.json" for 81.84.100.109 at Fri May 13 06:04:11 -0700 2011
2011-05-13T13:04:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by ApiController#api_bounces as JSON
2011-05-13T13:04:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"api_id"=>"69399ead0ed4ded38e7a101f7c8faf", "init"=>"2011-2-1"}
2011-05-13T13:04:57+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H11 (Backlog too deep) -> GET bapi.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-05-13T13:05:05+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> GET bapi.heroku.com/api/v1/69399ead0ed4ded38e7a101f7c8faf/2011-2-1.json dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-05-13T13:05:20+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> GET bapi.heroku.com/api/v1/69399ead0ed4ded38e7a101f7c8faf/2011-2-1.json dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-05-13T13:05:36+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> GET bapi.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-05-13T13:05:36+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> GET bapi.heroku.com/api/v1/69399ead0ed4ded38e7a101f7c8faf/2011-2-1.json dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
```

I can't understand why, that never happened before with other apps.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a Backlog too deep error. Are you running on a single dyno? Your upload would be consuming that dyno so any additional requests would be being queued.

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/backlog-too-deep

John.